# How to get customized TestNG reports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to get reports as the print statements in my code should also get printed in the report.
Example:

```
system.out.println("test case 2 started");
...
system.out.println("test case 2 finished");
```

I want this to get printed in the reports. Can anyone help on this

Comment: Documentation can help: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Reporter.log, you can log what ever content you needed. 
http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Reporter.html

Comment: log() function helped me to print in the reports. I got my reports as I wanted and customized more features now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANT to print the report in that you can do the editing.

Comment: I used ant and got my reports. But I want the print statements in the code to print in the reports :( Any idea ??